# Combine regex expression with negation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following strings

```
http://google.com/q=search<p>dfgdfg</p> 
https://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
```

My regex looks like this :

```
/(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))()[^\s]+)/g
```

How can I exclude the `<p>dfgdfg</p>`

from my search string so only the real urls will be chosen?

I know how to search for them but I want it in combination with my regex, so I need it in negation

```
<\/?(p)\b[^<>]*>
```

Here is a playground
https://regex101.com/r/4OlCyb/1

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Simply add all chars to `[^\s]+` that should not be in the link:

```
'http://google.com/?q=search<p>dfgdfg</p>'.match(/(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s<]+/)
```

Matches:

```
http://google.com/?q=search
```

You can add additional chars as needed to `[^\s<]+`